# how to evaluate an AutoModelForQuestionAnswering?

Tags: nlp, huggingface-transformers, bert-language-model

I'm using this AutoModelForQuestionAnswering from the transformers for semantic search. Therefore i could not find a way to evaluate it knowing that i'm do not have a predicted values and i don't have a train and test data.Here's the code.

```
 def load_model():
    model_name = "camembert-base"
    tokenizer = CamembertTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name)
   model = AutoModelForQuestionAnswering.from_pretrained(model_name)
    return model, tokenizer

    model,tokenizer= load_model()
    #input_ids are the indices corresponding to each token in the sentence.
    #input_ids = tokenizer.encode(search, text)
    encoded_output = tokenizer.encode_plus(text=search, text_pair=text, padding=True)
    input_ids = torch.tensor(encoded_output['input_ids'])
    attention_mask = torch.tensor(encoded_output['attention_mask'])
    token_type_ids = torch.tensor(0)
    tokens = tokenizer.convert_ids_to_tokens(input_ids)

    # Batch size of 1
    input_ids = input_ids.unsqueeze(0)
    token_type_ids = token_type_ids.unsqueeze(0)
    attention_mask = attention_mask.unsqueeze(0)

    print("this is the encode output", encoded_output)
    print("this is token_types_ids",token_type_ids)
    print("this is attention mask",attention_mask)
    print("this is input_ids",input_ids)
    print("this is tokens", tokens)

    output = model(input_ids=input_ids, token_type_ids=token_type_ids, attention_mask=attention_mask)

    print( model.eval() )

    # 3. GET THE ANSWER SPAN
    # once we have the most likely start and end tokens, we grab all the tokens between them
    # and convert tokens back to words!

    # tokens with highest start and end scores
    answer_start = torch.argmax(output.start_logits)  # get the most likely beginning of answer with the argmax of the score
    answer_end = torch.argmax(output.end_logits)
    if answer_end >= answer_start:
        answer = " ".join(tokens[answer_start:answer_end + 1])
    else:
        answer = "No Answer"
    return answer
```

'''